# Integration by substitution - where is the mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate $$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^{3/2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ by substituting $x=\cos z$ and $dx = -\sin z  \, dz$.

$x=-1  \implies z=-\pi $ and

$x=1 \implies z=0$.

I receive:

$$\int_{-\pi}^0 -(1-\cos^2z)^{3/2} \sin z \, dz = \int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin^4z \, dz $$

If I let WolframAlpha calculate those integrals, obviously somewhere a minus is missing: [Original](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%281-x%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%20from%20-1%20to%201) and [substituted](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+-sin%5E4+from+-pi+to+0)

What do I overlook?

EDIT: Inserted the correct link.

Comment: You linked to the same thing twice?

Comment: @user84413 no, it should be 4. 3 From the function and one from $dx$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You took the square root of the $\sin^2 z$ term, which by definition gives you $|\sin z|$. So the integrand simplifies to $$\int_{-\pi}^{0} - \sin z \cdot |\sin z|^3 \, \mathrm{d}z.$$

Since $\sin z$ is negative in the interval $(-\pi, 0)$ then $-\sin z$ is positive and hence the integrand is positive.

You can verify this works in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20-sin%20x%20%7Csin%20x%7C%5E3%20from%20-pi%20to%200) as well.

Comment: OP, don't feel bad, $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is among the top ten of most common careless errors.

Comment: Actually I am aware of that, but this time it was a bit "hidden" ;)